How to extract recurrent events from .ics file with R?
It's easy to import a ics-file in R with the library "calendar".
But in either way the recurrent events do not show up as single events (1 line per event as usually shown in a calender) but are hidden in these columns:

There are wo links mentioned in this issue but I cannot find out how to solve this.
Did anybody figure this out how to get 1 line of data per event (as usually shown in an event list)?
Thank you in advance!
Samuel
Edit:
I pasted an ics example with 1 singular event and 1 recurrening event) here on Pastebin that you can save into the file "gmail_calendar_export.ics".
Then read this file:

library(calendar)
df_cal <- calendar::ic_read("your specific path/gmail_calendar_export.ics")


can you give a link to an example file please? Otherwise we'll each have to create our own (I can't speak for anyone else, but I'm too lazy to do that)

The recurrence rule (RRULE) is there to avoid storing each single event in the first place. Package {almanac} provides utilities to generate the events from the rule.
